# Ambiguous dependencies for type EntityManagerFactory

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, cdi, jbpm, jboss-weld

I'm migrating from WF 7.4.0.FINAL to 16.0.0.FINAL. After resolving the upgrades of the different modules, I'm confronted with following: a WELD **Ambiguous dependency exception**. How can I keep the connection to both databases?

It seems the SessionFactory hibernate-core-5.3.9 is now extending from the EntityManagerFactory where it did not for hibernate-core-4.2.14 (WF7.4). The SessionFactory is defined in the HibernateProducer and a separate instance is injected in the EnvironmentProducer (specifically for jbpm). It seems these two are interfering with each other where it did not in Wildfly 7.4.

It connects to 2 databases: a jbpm and an application specific database. 
Both have a persistence.xml defined.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

public class HibernateProducer {


    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();

        return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public void closeSessionFactory(@Disposes SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

```
import org.jbpm.persistence.JpaProcessPersistenceContextManager;
import org.jbpm.persistence.jta.ContainerManagedTransactionManager;
import org.jbpm.process.audit.JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger;
import org.jbpm.process.core.timer.GlobalSchedulerService;
import org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.DefaultRuntimeEnvironment;
import org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.manager.InjectableRegisterableItemsFactory;
import org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.JPATaskPersistenceContextManager;
import org.kie.api.io.Resource;
import org.kie.api.io.ResourceType;
import org.kie.api.runtime.Environment;
import org.kie.api.runtime.EnvironmentName;
import org.kie.api.task.UserGroupCallback;
import org.kie.internal.runtime.manager.RuntimeEnvironment;
import org.kie.internal.runtime.manager.cdi.qualifier.PerProcessInstance;
import org.kie.internal.runtime.manager.cdi.qualifier.PerRequest;
import org.kie.internal.runtime.manager.cdi.qualifier.Singleton;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

@ApplicationScoped
public class EnvironmentProducer {

    @Inject
    protected BeanManager beanManager;
    @Inject
    protected CDIGlobalResolver globalResolver;
    @Inject
    protected GlobalSchedulerService schedulerService;
    @Inject
    protected UserGroupCallback userGroupCallback;
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "org.jbpm.domain")
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;

//  @Inject
//  protected ContainerManagedTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Inject
    private Instance<ResourceProducer> resourceProducers;

    @Produces
    @Singleton
    @PerRequest
    @PerProcessInstance
    public RuntimeEnvironment produceEnvironment() {

        DefaultRuntimeEnvironment runtimeEnvironment = new DefaultRuntimeEnvironment();
        runtimeEnvironment.addToConfiguration("drools.commandService",
                SingleThreadCommandService.class.getName());
        runtimeEnvironment.setEmf(emf);
        runtimeEnvironment.setSchedulerService(schedulerService);
        runtimeEnvironment.setUserGroupCallback(userGroupCallback);
        runtimeEnvironment
                .setRegisterableItemsFactory(InjectableRegisterableItemsFactory
                        .getFactory(beanManager, new JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger(
                                emf)));

        Environment env = runtimeEnvironment.getEnvironmentTemplate();
        runtimeEnvironment.addToConfiguration("drools.commandService",
                SingleThreadCommandService.class.getName());
        runtimeEnvironment.addToEnvironment(EnvironmentName.GLOBALS,
                globalResolver);
        runtimeEnvironment.addToEnvironment(
                EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, emf);
        runtimeEnvironment.addToEnvironment(
                EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER, new ContainerManagedTransactionManager());
        runtimeEnvironment.addToEnvironment(
                EnvironmentName.PERSISTENCE_CONTEXT_MANAGER,
                new JpaProcessPersistenceContextManager(env));
        runtimeEnvironment.addToEnvironment(
                EnvironmentName.TASK_PERSISTENCE_CONTEXT_MANAGER,
                new JPATaskPersistenceContextManager(env));

        for (ResourceProducer resourceProducer : resourceProducers) {
            ResourceType resourceType = resourceProducer.getResourceType();
            for (Resource resource : resourceProducer.getResources()) {
                runtimeEnvironment.addAsset(resource, resourceType);
            }
        }

        runtimeEnvironment.init();

        return runtimeEnvironment;
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    //@Named
    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return emf;
    }
}
```

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type EntityManagerFactory with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Inject public be.bside.process.jbpm.service.ProcessEngineService.init(EntityManagerFactory)
  at be.bside.process.jbpm.service.ProcessEngineService.init(ProcessEngineService.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Producer Method [SessionFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @ApplicationScoped public be.bside.common.store.HibernateProducer.getSessionFactory()],
  - Producer Method [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @ApplicationScoped public be.bside.process.jbpm.service.EnvironmentProducer.getEntityManagerFactory()]
```

Comment: I don't know how much of the code is under your control but you could perhaps use [CDI qualifiers](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#qualifiers) to differentiate between the two implementations. Alternatively, you can use [`@Typed`](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#restricting_bean_types) on the `SessionFactory` producer and list all the types you want except `EntityManagerFactory` so that it won't compete for IPs with the other producer.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to put [`@Typed(SessionFactory.class)`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/apidocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Typed.html) on your `HibernateProducer#getSessionFactory()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use two different EntityManagerFactories, then use Qualifiers, to distinguish.